# jquery onclick not working for append tags

Tags: jquery, append

I have append `<li>` tag with close class span tag

HTML code

```
<ul id="keyword">

</ul>
```

jquery

```
$("#btnadd").click(function() {
                addkey = document.getElementById("txtaddkey").value;
                if(addkey!=""){
                $('#keyword').append('<li><span>'+addkey+'</span><span class=\"amountin\"><a href=\"#\">$0.05</a> $ <input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"5\"/></span><span class=\'close ui-icon \'></span></li>');
                $('#txtaddkey').val('');
                }
            });
    $(".close").click(function (){
                $(this).parent().remove();  
            });
```

after li append in the ul tag I am try remove the li tag by click close icon but event not working.

Could you please any help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the `click` directly to the newly create element:

```
$("#btnadd").click(function() {
             // Made it a local variable by using "var"
            var addkey = document.getElementById("txtaddkey").value;
            if(addkey!=""){
                $('<li><span>'+addkey+'</span><span class=\"amountin\"><a href=\"#\">$0.05</a> $ <input type=\"text\" maxlength=\"5\"/></span><span class=\'close ui-icon \'></span></li>')
                    .find('.close').click(function (){
                        $(this).parent().remove();  
                    })
                    .end().appendTo('#keyword');
                $('#txtaddkey').val('');
            }
        });
```

or if there are going to be several of these,  better to use `.delegate()` as seen [in @Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228341/jquery-onclick-not-working-for-append-tags/4228378#4228378).

Answer (score 7):

Use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) here, like this:

```
$("#keyword").delegate(".close", "click", function (){
  $(this).parent().remove();  
});
```

[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) works by adding an event handler on `#keyword` (the `<ul>`) which listens for events to bubble up...it works on current and newly added `.close` elements beneath it.  The less efficient [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) version looks like this:

```
$(".close").live("click", function (){
  $(this).parent().remove();  
});
```

Comment: your answer also correct but I have use below code. Thanks Nick!!

Comment: @Elankeeran - you can do this...but it's *far* less efficient, why not attach the handler just once?

Comment: @Elankeeran - That's a separate question, you should ask it as such so it helps others.

Comment: Can't believe I've only found out about .delegate now, thanks! What are the performance issues (if any) of using it?

Comment: @Adam - It simply listens at a higher level so the event (which would bubble anyway) gets caught there.  The cost is that the listener is checking all events of that type that go through it.  For example: another click on a child that doesn't match the `.close` selector is going to be checked if it matches `.close` when the event happens, nothing will happen if it doesn't...but that check still has to happen.  So `.delegate()` isn't the best for say `<body>`, but even then you wouldn't notice any difference unless you're page was * extremely* large and complicated...and probably not even then.

Comment: Thank you for including the live code for reference.  That made it easier to see what was going on and implement.